# Getting HTML markup in directive element parameter

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/SSzoCgtrIATx9YGqHqC2?p=preview) I have a directive that is declared with an UL element.

```
<directive>
  <ul>
    <li id="0">xxx 0</li>        
    <li id="1">xxx 1</li>        
    <li id="2">xxx 2</li>        
  </ul>
</directive>
```

I'm trying to retrieve these by analyzing the `element` parameter in the directive link function, but I only get them in the innerHTML. What I need is to get the id and text of the `li` elements as DOM. Any ideas?

```
angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app').directive('directive', function() {
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'AE';
    directive.scope = true;
    directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {      
        console.log(element)
    };
    return directive;
});
```

Comment: do you want this result : http://plnkr.co/edit/baeGA2wbMuZkQRW5vlY7?p=preview

Comment: @Natiq No it is still plain text like that.

Comment: This seems really backwards. What generates the html in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have element in directive you dont have to use querySelector,

you can directly do,

```
directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(element.find("ul")[0].children);
};
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/odDmKsxrP6jQyajX4zUL?p=info)**

Comment: this works, however it doesn't if the directive has a template, any idea how to fix this? see error in console http://plnkr.co/edit/Wy058Wqh2c7im0LhQQLC?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. If you log the element then you will see that it is an array like object and you need to select the key of the array first in order to get the HTML element.

```
.directive('directive', function() {

var directive = {};
directive.restrict = 'AE';
directive.scope = true;
directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    console.log(element[0].querySelector('ul'));//Element is an array like object
};
return directive;
```

});

http://plnkr.co/edit/ajLmjxnDJ1JXjkk86aRh?p=preview

Comment: *"Element is an array"* ... no , it is an *array like object*.